# How to modify Laravel model collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 database tables. The first table is the `files` that have a link (and other parameters) to a file on the server. The second table has a `file_id` column that stores the id of the line with the file in the `files` table. How can I make a join element from the table `files` on querying to model. Getting a collection and adding an image in a loop is not suitable. I need something like a function called when accessing a model (not a __construct ()), something as accessor, but for collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the relationship so it will have the file as part of the Model that contains `file_id`.

On the Model that has `file_id`, add a `hasOne` relationship for the `File` model:

```
public function file()
{
    return $this->hasOne(File::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

You can define the inverse on the `File` model:

```
public function otherModel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OtherModel::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship

This will allow you to eager load the `File` when you access the other model.

You can eager load as you go using the `with()` method:

```
$otherModel = OtherModel::with('file')->...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading-morphto-relationships

Or eager load every time you access the other model by adding the `$with` to the model it self:

```
protected $with = ['file'];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

--

You will then get the `File` as part of your other Model like so:

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'file_id' => 4,
    'file' => [
        'id' => 11,
         ...,
    ],
    ...,
],
```

--

Also, as you have defined the inverse relationship, you can eager load the other model when you access a `File` using `with()`;

```
$file = File::with('otherModel')->...
```

Or as shown above, eager load by default in the `File` model:

```
protected $with = ['otherModel'];
```